# Error crear Archivo XML con java

Tags: java

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente programa:

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder ={"Autor", "Nom", "Editorial","Isbn", "llibre"})

public class Llibreria extends MarshalClass{
    static String JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT;
    private String Autor;
    private String Nom;
    private String Editorial;
    private int Isbn;
    private ArrayList<LlistaLlibre> llibre;


    public String getAutor(){return Autor;}
    @XmlElement
    public void setAutor (String Autor){this.Autor =Autor;}

    public String getNom(){return Nom;}
    @XmlElement
    public void setNom (String Nom){this.Nom =Nom;}

    public String getEditorial(){return Editorial;}
    @XmlElement
    public void setEditorial (String Editorial){this.Editorial =Editorial;}

    public int getIsbn(){return Isbn;}
    @XmlElement
    public void setIsbn (int Isbn){this.Isbn =Isbn;}

    public ArrayList <LlistaLlibre> getLlibre() { return llibre;}
    @XmlElement
    public void setLlibre(ArrayList<LlistaLlibre> llibre){ this.llibre= llibre;}

}



package exercici3;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
@XmlRootElement(name="llibr")

class LlistaLlibre extends MarshalClass {

    private String autor;
    private String nom;
    private String editorial;
    private int isbn;

    public String getAutor(){ return autor;}
    @XmlElement
    public void setAutor (String autor){ this.autor = autor;}

    public String getNom(){ return nom;}
    @XmlElement
    public void setNom (String nom){ this.nom = nom;}

    public String getEditorial(){ return editorial;}
    @XmlElement
    public void setEditorial (String editorial){ this.editorial = editorial;}

     public int getIsbn(){ return isbn;}
    @XmlElement
    public void setIsbn (int isbn){ this.isbn = isbn;}


    }




package exercici3;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
public class MarshalClass {

    public void generateXML (String nameFile) {

        try{
            File file = new File (nameFile);
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(this.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jc.createMarshaller();

            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Llibreria.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, new FileWriter(nameFile, true));

        }catch (JAXBException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


package exercici3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */
public class LlibreriaEscriure {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        EscriureLlibreria();

    }

    private static void EscriureLlibreria() {

        Llibreria cc = new Llibreria();
        cc.setAutor("Xavier");
        cc.setNom("Nosotros dos");
        cc.setEditorial("Columna");
        cc.setIsbn(978-84-664-2228-4);

        ArrayList<LlistaLlibre> alCU = new ArrayList<LlistaLlibre>();
        int init = 2000;
                for (int i =1; i<1000;i++){
        LlistaLlibre cu = new LlistaLlibre();
        cu.setAutor(""+i);
        cu.setNom(""+i);
        cu.setEditorial(""+i);
        cu.setIsbn(i);
        alCU.add(cu);       
    }
                cc.setLlibre(alCU);
                cc.generateXML("llibres.xml");


    }

}
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
run:
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 8 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
La propiedad autor existe, pero no está especificada en @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String exercici3.Llibreria.getAutor()
        at exercici3.Llibreria
La propiedad editorial existe, pero no está especificada en @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String exercici3.Llibreria.getEditorial()
        at exercici3.Llibreria
La propiedad isbn existe, pero no está especificada en @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int exercici3.Llibreria.getIsbn()
        at exercici3.Llibreria
La propiedad nom existe, pero no está especificada en @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String exercici3.Llibreria.getNom()
        at exercici3.Llibreria
La propiedad Autor aparece en @XmlType.propOrder, pero no existe. Quizá quiso decir autor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at exercici3.Llibreria
La propiedad Nom aparece en @XmlType.propOrder, pero no existe. Quizá quiso decir nom.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at exercici3.Llibreria
La propiedad Editorial aparece en @XmlType.propOrder, pero no existe. Quizá quiso decir editorial.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at exercici3.Llibreria
La propiedad Isbn aparece en @XmlType.propOrder, pero no existe. Quizá quiso decir isbn.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at exercici3.Llibreria

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:445)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at exercici3.MarshalClass.generateXML(MarshalClass.java:25)
    at exercici3.LlibreriaEscriure.EscriureLlibreria(LlibreriaEscriure.java:41)
    at exercici3.LlibreriaEscriure.main(LlibreriaEscriure.java:18)
```

Podéis ayudarme?

EDITO

He hecho modificaciones en el código pero ahora tengo este otro error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name parameter must not be null
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.setProperty(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.setProperty(MarshallerImpl.java:527)
    at exercici3.MarshalClass.generateXML(MarshalClass.java:28)
    at exercici3.LlibreriaEscriure.EscriureLlibreria(LlibreriaEscriure.java:37)
    at exercici3.LlibreriaEscriure.main(LlibreriaEscriure.java:14)
C:\Users\Montse\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser necesariamente con JAXB o puedes usar otra librería?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que se debe a malas practicas en tu código. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Llibreria extends MarshalClass{
    static String JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT;
    private String Autor;
    private String Nom;
    private String Editorial;
    private int Isbn;
    private ArrayList<LlistaLlibre> llibre;
```

Todas las variables empiezan con mayúscula a excepción de llibre y si te das cuenta es la única que no aparece en el error. En java los nombres de variables deben comenzar en minúscula y las clases en mayúscula, para que la convención de nombrado funcione correctamente con los getters y setters (Los getters y setters están bien nombrados en tu código). Esta convención están fuerte que frameworks como hibernate la usan mucho.

```
private String autor;
@XmlElement
public String getAutor(){return autor;}
public void setAutor (String autor){this.autor =autor;}
```

Y otra cosa que observo es que la anotación `@XmlElement` debe ir en los getters y no en los setters como lo estas poniendo, ya que indica que de ahí se obtendrá el valor de un tag del xml.

Estos cambios implican que la anotacion `@XmlType` cambia a `@XmlType(propOrder ={"autor", "nom", "editorial","isbn", "llibre"})`

Comment: Me sale otro error.. Edito

Comment: Difícil saber sin el nuevo código, pero adivinando, puede ser porque la lista `private ArrayList<LlistaLlibre> llibre;` no esta instanciada y hay que instanciarla `private ArrayList<LlistaLlibre> llibre=new ArrayList<LlistaLlibre>();`